# How to use react-phone-number-input with Formik's Field component

Tags: reactjs, field, formik

I'm using Formik and trying to use this package, but Formik can't see the value of the input and thus doesn't validate or submit the form.

Here's the PhonInputField component that I'm using ...

```
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-number-input";

const PhoneInputField = ({
    field,
    form
}) => {
    return (
        <div className="input-field">
            <PhoneInput
                placeholder="Enter phone number"
                name={field.name}
                value={field.value}
                onChange={field.onChange}
                onBlur={field.onBlur}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default PhoneInputField;
```

And here's how I'm using it in Formik ...

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={signInSchema}
    onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
>
    {({
        isValid,
        isSubmitting,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur
    }) => (
        <Form>


                <Field
                    type="tel"
                    name="phone_number"
                    component={PhoneInputField}
                />

            <div className="cta">
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting}
                    className="btn btn-primary big"
                >Submit</button>
            </div>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

=======================================================

I tried to ask this question on the Github repo page for this project but with no luck.

I also tried to do it like this ...

```
<PhoneInput
        placeholder="Enter phone number"
        name={field.name}
        value={field.value}
        onChange={value => field.onChange({ value })}
        onBlur={value => field.onBlur({ value })}
/>
```

But still, Formik can't see the field value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those of you who may come across this question, it was answered in the Github repo page here ...

https://github.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input/issues/298#issuecomment-557746103

Answer (score 2):

```
onChange={(phone, country) =>
    setValues({
    ...values,
    phone: phone,
    countryCode: country.countryCode
    })
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion